# How can I specifically target this element id with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

```
<div id=checkout>
<form id="confirmation" class="center">
<p>content</p>
</form>
</div>
```

I have a CSS selector `#checkout form.center` already being used

i would like to override this specifically for the confirmation form, but none of the things I try to write get applied. I should think that `#confirmation form.center` or something should supercede the first rule, but it doesn't even seem to hit the target. `#confirmation` gets overridden by the above mentioned selector because it's not as specific.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expanding on BoltClock's answer:

Each CSS selector has a [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) value. For each element, in case of a conflict for the value of one of its properties, the rule with highest specificity takes precedence. Generally, the more and better information in a CSS selector, the greater its specificity.

For this reason, adding something appropriate to your existing selector (`#checkout form.center`) will enable you to override it:

```
#checkout form.center {
  /* your existing CSS */
}

#checkout #confirmation {
  /* your overrides; this has higher specificity */
}

#checkout form#confirmation {
  /* this would also work -- even higher specificity */
}

#checkout form#confirmation.center {
  /* even higher */
}

#checkout form.center p {
  /* works inside the p only, but also has
     greater specificity than #checkout form.center  */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need to specifically override your existing selector, use:

```
#checkout #confirmation
```

The reason why `#confirmation form.center` doesn't work is because that selects `form.center` that sits *within* a `#confirmation` element, which isn't the same. You would have written it as this instead:

```
#checkout form#confirmation.center
```

but that's way overkill; the first selector I suggest is specific enough to override your first selector.